# pgAdmin 4 v3.3 Download as CSV button not working

Tags: export, export-to-csv, pgadmin-4

My **Download to CSV (F8)** button is not working.  I have a view open and want to export to CSV.  It was working, and then I changed nothing and it was not working.  I just installed the new version (pgAdmin 4 v3.3) to see if that would fix it.  Still it does not work.  The **Tools>Import/Export...** is grayed-put, also.
It does seem like I see a milli-sec refresh to the screen, like something is happening.  But I get nothing.  It's not in my downloads.  Is this a browser thing?  I'm using Chrome 69.0.3497.100.
I have looked for answers, not finding anything.
I would so very much appreciate an answer!!  I am frustrated!
pgAdmin 4 v3.3 with Postgres 9.5, windows

Answer (score 1):

You have to be in "View/Edit data" mode, so that you can see the rows you want to export as csv. Only then can you access the down arrow (Download as csv)

Comment: The CSV export recently has stopped working (Firefox 65.0.1, Ubuntu 16, PgAdmin 4.3) (even if the button is not greed out).

(And AFAIK there is no need to view the data first, but I can be mistaken.)

Comment: This would be the patch, but I don't know how to apply it in Ubuntu (PgAdmin was installed via snap).

https://redmine.postgresql.org/projects/pgadmin4/repository/revisions/2356988bdfef515d88c10c7b0ed6c5b7a9838358/diff/web/pgadmin/tools/sqleditor/static/js/sqleditor.js?utf8=%E2%9C%93&type=sbs

Comment: So the issue appears in 4.3 and would be solved in 4.4.

Comment: On Windows, I can confirm that it didn't work on 4.21, but works on 4.22.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and maybe this is how it is supposed to work, but I had multiple queries in the SQL window which I was highlighting to run. Trying to download as CSV just resulted in the flash of a dialog as you say. Investigating the network Tab I noticed that the request to the server was failing.

You need to highlight the query you want to extract as CSV, otherwise it seems to run the whole window. It is not, as you would expect just processing the result window.

This was version 4.23 running inside Docker.